# How do I configure VS Code to debug an opensource project written in Java that uses ANT as its build command?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, debugging, ant

I'm trying to fix an opensource project using VS Code as my main ide that is a fairly complicated project written in Java, and it would go alot more quickly if I could actually do a step through of certain pieces of code to make sure they are indeed being touched during a run.

The project uses an ant build.xml file to compile it, one of its output options being a jar file, but it also does seem to precompile the package into a build directory.

Is there a way I can update the launch config or some other configuration to turn on debugging and use the 'compile' action it provides as default and tell it where to launch from ?

I have the microsoft extension pack for java, but its not doing anything but showing me a million classes and asking me which is the main, also doesn't seem to be attempting to build anything.

Thanks in advance.

I expected that the debugger package would have been written to parse the build.xml and also determine where the main point of entry was on its own and launch that class, along with a debugging server of some sort.

Comment: I don’t use VS Code, so just a guess that you might want to instead use [*Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/).

Comment: You can configure [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch) to change debugging options. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes/                  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: @ jialedu and once upon a time i did that and had the fun of lookig it up. yay.

Comment: @JialeDu I kind of meant right out of the box, it detects the main class and just runs in debugging mode like it should without extract configuration.